# Running two motors in one tube

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm looking at the option of running two blinds motors in one tube, running in alternate rotations so that they can help to lift more weight.

My understanding is that the dominant motor will slow to the other motor but when under load (lifting blind) they will kick in together. These motors are 1.1Nm but struggle to lift the blind, we tried a hard wire running at 1.5Nm but still it struggled.

So if I put two of the battery ones together it should run about 2Nm?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by running in alternate rotations? 1.1Nm seems to be very little. What kind of blinds are you trying to lift (weight) and what's the diameter of the tube? With that information you could calculate how much torque you need. The quick general answer though is yes, you can simply add the torques.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. They are tube motors  and they are lifting roughly 5-10kg fabric and bars. It's a pleated freehang blind that we make, running off a roller blind bar. The motor slides inside the bar using a crown at the end to turn it. The tube is 32mm using 0.8mm cording.